# My txt to CSV code drops everything into one column

Tags: powershell, csv, text

I've tried so many different approaches and I cannot figure out how to get my code to work so that my text > CSV conversion has the data separated into same structure as the text file. Everything just drops into one column.

This is my current code:

```
# Define the path to your text files
$textFilePath = "C:\test"

# Define the path where you want to save the CSV files
$csvOutputPath = "C:\test"

# Use Get-ChildItem to list text files in the specified directory
$textFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $textFilePath -Filter "*.txt"

# Loop through each text file and convert it to a CSV
foreach ($textFile in $textFiles) {
    # Read the content of the text file
    $content = Get-Content -Path $textFile.FullName

    # Process the content and convert it to CSV format
    # Here, we assume that the text file is structured in a way
    # that each line represents a row, and columns are separated by a delimiter
    $csvContent = $content | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Header Name

    # Construct the CSV file path for output
    $csvFileName = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($textFile.Name, ".csv")
    $csvFileOutputPath = Join-Path -Path $csvOutputPath -ChildPath $csvFileName

    # Export the data to a CSV file
    $csvContent | Export-Csv -Path $csvFileOutputPath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Force
}

Write-Host "Text files converted to CSV files in $csvOutputPath."
```

Comment: You only provide one header name `Name`. Does your input files only have one column? You may share some sample lines of one of your input files (formatted as cope please)

Comment: You're telling the cmdlet you only want one column: `-Header Name` so what is happening is what is expected. Also, if those files are already Csvs it doesn't make sense to read them and export them again without doing anything aside

Comment: Unrelated to the single column issue which already has comments, getting and storing the content of each file in variable `$content` is not needed and is just locking up memory needlessly.  You can pipe `Get-Content` directly to `Convert-FromCsv`.  This is also unnecessary as you could skip Get-Content altogether and do `Import-Csv -Path $textFile -Delimiter ";" -Header Name`

Comment: What is the input structure?  All you have told us is that the input uses semicolon as a field separator, and that there is only one column, with name "Name".  This is in the ConvertFrom-Csv code.